# Refresh app in Amplify with AWS and Next JS

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, next.js, aws-amplify

I'm trying to get updated my frontend app with Next JS in Amplify service of AWS but it doesn't refresh.

Steps I follow:

1. Commit and push my code.
2. Amplify detect the changes in my GitHub repo.
3. Amplify starts deployment
4. All was successfull.
5. I try the app but the deployed verion it doesn't have the last changes.

I reviewed the history log and Amplify it's taking the last commit.

Any suggest?

Thanks in advance.